# Is it possible to combine composite builds and typesafe project accessors?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building an android-app with the following modules:

```
app
 |> presentation (android module)
 |> domain (jvm module)
 |> androidkit (shared company-wide; included as a composite build of a git submodule)
```

This works fine using the following gradle setup:

```
// settings.gradle.kts of project
include(
    ":app",
    ":presentation",
    ":domain",
)

// https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html
includeBuild("androidkit")
```

---

```
// build.gradle.kts of app
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":domain"))
    implementation(project(":presentation"))
    implementation("androidkit")
    ...
}
```

I now would like to use [typesafe project accessors](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html) as suggested [here in this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/using-type-safe-project-dependencies-on-gradle-493ab7337aa):

```
// settings.gradle.kts of project
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

dependencies {
    implementation(projects.domain)
    implementation(projects.presentation)
    implementation(projects.androidkit) // TODO doesn't compile
```

This works fine for both the `presentation` and `domain` modules.
However, it doesn't work for the included build `androidkit`.
How can i make this work?

I've tried various different ways of writing this, but none seemed to work (e.g. implementation(androidkit).